# Array multi conditional filter using operators

Tags: javascript

I have a data array that I want to filter based on if set variables are set to true or false. I want to write my code in a single function using operators (if possible) instead of having to code for every combination. My data sample looks like this:

```
chardata = [
     {
    "CharName": "Char1",
     "Magic": TRUE,
     "Melee": TRUE,
     "Ranged": TRUE
    },{
     "CharName": "Char2",
     "Magic": TRUE,
     "Melee": FALSE,
     "Ranged": FALSE
    },{
    "CharName": "Char3",
     "Magic": FALSE,
     "Melee": FALSE,
     "Ranged": TRUE
    }
]
```

I would like the filter to return Char1 whenever Magic and Ranged are set to true, but not return Char2 or Char3.

```
const filter = chardata.filter(function (ef) {
      return Magic === true ? 
      ef["Magic"] === true : "",
      Ranged === true ? 
      ef["Melee"] === true : "",
      Melee === true ? 
      ef["Ranged"] === true : ""})
```

Is is possible to make this work using this method or are are more than one functions needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The main issue making a clean solution difficult is your `Magic` and `Range` variables, which are standalone instead of being in an easier to manage structure like an object.

Consolidate them into an object. Eg instead of

```
Magic = true;
Melee = false;
Ranged = true;
```

have

```
charType = {
  Magic: true,
  Melee: false,
  Ranged: true
}
```

Then you can do:

```
const filter = chardata.filter((oneChar) => {
  return Object.entries(charType)
    .filter(entry => entry[1])
    .every(([key, value]) => oneChar[key] === value);
});
```

Live demo:

```js
chardata = [
     {
    "CharName": "Char1",
     "Magic": true,
     "Melee": true,
     "Ranged": true
    },{
     "CharName": "Char2",
     "Magic": true,
     "Melee": false,
     "Ranged": false
    },{
    "CharName": "Char3",
     "Magic": false,
     "Melee": false,
     "Ranged": true
    }
]

const charType = {
  Magic: true,
  Melee: false,
  Ranged: true
};


const filter = chardata.filter((oneChar) => {
  return Object.entries(charType)
    .filter(entry => entry[1])
    .every(([key, value]) => oneChar[key] === value);
});

console.log(filter);
```

```css
strict mode
```